# php I cannot get the filename correctly from fullpath

Tags: php, filenames

I have this entry like below in a database

```
../admin/students/georgeekpla1/HKS3/第12课.pdf
../admin/students/georgeekpla1/HKS2/Μάθημα 1.pdf
```

and I want to get the filename from the fullpath.
I need filename `第12课.pdf` and `Μάθημα 1.pdf`

I have tried using

1. `$file = basename($getFullPath);`
2. `$file = pathinfo($getFullPath ,PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

I check the results with echo

```
echo "F: ".$file;
```

and I get:

```
F: 1
F: 12课
```

What is wrong? Why it trim characters?

Comment: Did you read and follow the **Caution** in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)?

Comment: I missed the setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8"); I added it and now work fine. Many thanks